# Python Get Returned Object From Called Module

Tags: python, object, module, spyder

Given this module (sample.py):

```
def calculation(x):
   r = x + 1
   return r
```

In my main .py file in Spyder, I'm calling it like this:

```
import sample
b = sample.calculation(2)
```

My (dumb) question is: 
how to I access r, as defined in the sample module, for other calculations in the main .py file from which I'm calling sample?

I want to continue by doing something like:

```
a = r/2
```

in the main .py file after calling

```
sample.calculation(2)
```

Update:

I would assume b would result in the number 3.
But what if the module returns 2 different numbers (objects)? How do I access them individually?

Comment: I don't quite get the question.  You store the result in `b`, so why don't you just do `a = b / 2`?

Comment: Modules don't return things. Functions return things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing another module's variable is possible by making it global. But it is not a good practice and often avoided. You can do this instead

```
import sample
r = sample.calculation(2)
```

This way, you can use the same variable name 'r' but it is now a local variable.

For your second question about returning multiple objects from a module, you can do this

```
def module1(x):
    return x+1,x+2

a,b = module1(5)
#a has 5+1 = 6 
#b has 5+2 = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

> My (dumb) question is: how to I access r, as defined in the sample module, for other calculations in the main .py file from which I'm calling sample?

You use that `b` variable you assigned the value to.

> But what if the module returns 2 different numbers (objects)? How do I access them individually?

If you mean the function does this:

```
def return_two_things():
    return 1, 2
```

then you assign them to two variables:

```
a, b = module.return_two_things()
```

If you mean the function does this:

```
def wrong_way():
    return 1
    return 2
```

then your function is wrong, and you have misunderstood how `return` statements work. A function ends as soon as it executes a `return`; it does not continue on to return more things.